# Update or Clear the cache of specific route in nuxt keep-alive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, keep-alive

I am using `<Nuxt keep-alive/>` in `layouts/default.vue` to cache the request. But when I change some data I want to update the cache or Destroy the cache so that next time when we visit the page the data is up to date.